# Разобрать код на java

Tags: java

```
public void sortAmmunitionsByCost() {
        System.out.println("*******SORTING BY COST********");
        Collections.sort(ammunitions, new Comparator() {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                Ammunition a1 = (Ammunition) o1;
                Ammunition a2 = (Ammunition) o2;
                if (a1.getCost() > a2.getCost()) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if (a2.getCost() > a1.getCost()) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
```

Помогите подробно разобрать этот код - я не понимаю здесь в метод вложен метод?

Comment: [Collections.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-)

Comment: У вас какая-то джава 15-летней давности. Сейчас пишут так: `ammunitions.sort(Comparator.comparing(Ammunition::getCost));` вместо тринадцати строчек в вашем примере. Если это какой-то учебник или тюториал, выкиньте его и возьмите чего-нибудь поновее.

Answer (score 3):

Приведенный вами код более-менее идентичен коду:

```
public void sortAmmunitionsByCost() {
     System.out.println("*******SORTING BY COST********");
    Collections.sort(ammunitions, new MyComparator());
}

class MyComparator implements Comparator {
   public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            Ammunition a1 = (Ammunition) o1;
            Ammunition a2 = (Ammunition) o2;
            if (a1.getCost() > a2.getCost()) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (a2.getCost() > a1.getCost()) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
 }
```

В вашем примере просто приведена укороченная форма его записи, где применяется т.н. *анонимный класс*, то есть чтобы не городить огород вокруг класса `MyComparator`, который все равно используется только один раз - применена конструкция с анонимным классом.

Почитайте [туториал по анонимным классам](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Answer (score 2):

Метод `sort` в данном случае принимает два аргумента - список `ammunitions` и компаратор.

В данном случае вы просто не можете сравнить два объекта класса Ammunition одним оператором сравнения (>, <, >=, <=).

Вам необходимо передать функцию, в данном случае `compare`, в теле которой необходимо реализовать сравнение объектов этого класса. В Вашем коде сравниваются поля `cost`, путем получения их значений через геттеры (`getCost()`).

Comment: Но ведь мы же не создавали обьект Collections

Comment: @Валерий так это и не объект, а класс.

Comment: Тоесть мы вызываем метод класса

Comment: @Валерий да. Вас это чем-то удивляет?

Comment: в классе Collections определен static метод sort. Поскольку List наследуется от Collections, то мы можем использовать с ним метод sort()

Comment: Чет я не доучил Как в методе класса появляется еще метод внутри?

Comment: Первый метод, т.е. sort принимает в качестве своих аргументов список и функцию сравнения. Поскольку у Вас нет отдельной функции для сравнения, которую Вы бы передали, вы реализуете эту самую функцию прямо внутри sort(лист, Ваша функция сравнения);

Comment: Теперь догнал! С методом я тупанул действительно у нас же метод статичные значит вызываем по имени класса а вот про обьект класса comparator не знал

Comment: А почему ему функция передается в фигурных скобках а не в круглых как аргумент

Comment: я понял это то что возвращает функция передается в качестве аргумента?

Comment: Вы могли бы передать, как аргумент, уже готовую функцию. Результат был бы таким `Collections.sort(list, comparator()). Но Вы реализуете компаратор внутри параметров, поэтому там же принимаете аргументы и пишете реализацию, как в обычном методе. Collections.sort(list, int comparator(аргументы) { реализация });

Comment: но метод compare же нигде не реализуется или при создании обьекта класса Comparator он сразу и реализуется?

Comment: Compartor - это не класс, а интерфейс. В интерфейсах нет реализаций, только лишь факт того, что такой метод будет обязательно реализован. Т.е. вы реализуете его сразу при "создании".